# Reverse Geocoding Using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, geocoding, reverse, google-maps

My project runs on J2ME and requires me to get the user current street address. I am able to get the user coordinates using location based. But how do i go about getting the street address??

I know google map does the reverse geocoding. But how can i link that to my application?? And will there be any legal issues too??

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are legal issues with using Google Maps within J2ME apps. The Google Maps API can only be used from within a browser.

See 10.8 on this page: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Google Maps also has a limit on the number of unique maps you can download per ip address. Usually it would be good enough for any PC-based app. However, on mobile devices many devices will go via a proxy web service such that many devices have the same IP address. Because of that the limit is reached very quickly.

Yahoo Maps has no such restrictions in it's T&Cs and a much higher limit per ip address. They also flag certain ip address as proxy servers so they don't count towards the limits. We've used this commercially.

As for reverse GeoCoding, there is the GeoNames webservice, though I've not personally used it.

Comment: Hi Wex,
Thanks for the reply.. as for your url, i have glance through it before. The problem is that, that web service doesnt provides the postal codes for me country. Btw i am from Singapore...

As for your yahoo maps?? So yahoo also have something similar to google map too?? ie reverse geo coding..

Comment: We've not done any reverse geo-coding commercially; just in R&D. One of our failsafe methods involved having a database in the app of all the postcodes and their area coverage. With some smart lookup calls (point-in-polygon) it works fine... but it is a huge dataset (we were doing this in the UK). Else running your own server will also do the job, and it's possible to update the dataset without updating the app. All depends on what your final aim is.

Answer (score 2):

Java ME does actually standardize native reverse geocoding as part of JSR 293 Location API 2.0:
http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/JSR_293_Location_API_2_0/index.html?javax/microedition/location/services/GeocodingServiceProvider.html

Section "4.2.2. Geocoding" in the below paper describes reverse geoding using Location API 2.0 in Java ME:
http://www.locationaware.usf.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Barbeau-Location-API-2.0-for-J2ME-COMCOM3573.pdf

However, currently JSR 293 is not widely implemented in commercially-available Java ME mobile phones, at least those available in the U.S.  Instead, most phones still implement JSR179 Location API 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply, but I was actually looking for the same thing and now I have finally done it.

What you need to do:

- Send a request to the Google server by opening a HTTP connection on J2ME and then you will get response from Google either in XML or JSON based on the HTTP link you request.
- Parse this response in order to retrieve the location from the XML or JSON document.

  - For XML, I would suggest using kXML 1.2 Parser
  - For JSON parsing using the json.org parser.

You can send me a mail if you are still stuck with it since I am through that phase already :). 
Mail me at prateek.football@gmail.com